# Filter layer by using symbology as toggle in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, filter, definition-query

Is there a way to customize ArcMap 10.7.1 so that users can filter layers by simply clicking the layer's symbology in the table of contents?
 
For example, is there a way to add a toggle/checkbox to each level in a layer's symbology that users could click to include/exclude the features from the map?

- Or alternatively, select the symbol's label/text to include the features in the map. And deselect the symbol's label/text to exclude the features.
- Or another way of approaching it might be: enable an option in the layer's properties that allows users to generate a definition query by simply clicking in the symbology.

This functionality would add efficiency to day-to-day work by eliminating the need to write tedious definition queries (WHERE clauses with IN operator) just to include/exclude a certain type of feature from a layer.

Comment: In properties, symbology select ones you don't need and remove.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at a similar suggestion on ArcGIS Ideas (see link below), no, it does not look like this is currently possible.

- [Toggle visibility for individual Categories on Symbology tab](https://community.esri.com/ideas/3815)